# Extract number from string and compare problem

Tags: strings, etoolbox, xstring

I try to extract the year, month and day from a string and write different text depending on the given date. I thought I could use `xstring` and `etoolbox`, but I can'st get it to work. Here's the code snippet:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Datum}{04.12.2011}

\newcommand{\Jahr}{\StrBehind[2]{\Datum}{.}}
\newcommand{\Monat}{\StrBetween[1,2]{\Datum}{.}{.}}
\newcommand{\Tag}{\StrBefore[1]{\Datum}{.}}

Jahr: \Jahr

\ifnumcomp{\Jahr}{=}{2011}{Jahr eq 2011}{Jahr neq 2011}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
pdflatex> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
pdflatex> <to be read again> 
pdflatex>                    \let 
pdflatex> l.11 {305}
pdflatex>           
pdflatex> ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
pdflatex> <to be read again>
```

But `\Jahr` seems to correctly contain `2011`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. When asking questions about problems one is encountering with (La)TeX code, it is helpful to provide a complete Minimum Working Example (MWE) rather than code snippets. To help debug problems, it's generally also helpful to provide information about the TeX distribution one is using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please avoid providing code snippets; instead, do create a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

You are passing the complete `xstring`-test to `ifnumcomp`. That fails. You can save the the result of the `xstring`-test by the optional argument of `\StrBehind` and pass this to `\ifnumcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Datum}{04.12.2011}

\StrBehind[2]{\Datum}{.}[\Jahr]
\StrBetween[1,2]{\Datum}{.}{.}[\Monat]
\StrBefore[1]{\Datum}{.}[\Tag]

Jahr: \Jahr

\ifnumcomp{\Jahr}{=}{2011}{Jahr eq 2011}{Jahr neq 2011}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you want to combine the output and the test you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Datum[1]{\@datum{#1}\@executetest{#1}}
\def\@datum#1{#1}
\def\@executetest#1{%
\StrBehind[2]{#1}{.}[\Jahr]
\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{.}{.}[\Monat]
\StrBefore[1]{#1}{.}[\Tag]
}
\begin{document}
\Datum{04.12.2011}

Jahr: \Jahr

\ifnumcomp{\Jahr}{=}{2011}{Jahr eq 2011}{Jahr neq 2011}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Modern parsing packages take care of some things that probably should be taken care of, but sometimes (or just as an illustrative example) it's simpler to use the TeX primitives directly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\datum{04.12.2011}

\def\Jahr{\expandafter\xJahr\datum\relax}
\def\Monat{\expandafter\xMonat\datum\relax}
\def\Tag{\expandafter\xTag\datum\relax}

\def\xJahr#1.#2.#3\relax{#3}
\def\xMonat#1.#2.#3\relax{#2}
\def\xTag#1.#2.#3\relax{#1}

\begin{document}


Jahr: \Jahr

\ifnum\Jahr=2011
Jahr eq 2011
\else
Jahr neq 2011
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for not shooting with cannon balls on sparrows and a good example of using TeX directly for parsing. For the sake of the "illustrativeness" of the example you might want to consider adding a bit of explanation to aid the beginner (e.g., how TeX matches argument patterns and the roles of `\expandafter` and `\relax`).

Comment: `\expandafter` makes `\datum` expand before `\xJahr`, so `\Jahr` is equivalent to `\xJahr 04.12.2011\relax`    then `\xJah` takes three arguments delimited by . or `\relax` and returns one of them. The `\relax` token is just used as a token to mark the end of the input here, it's never actually executed, and using an undefined command or a . or `\documentclass` would have worked just as well, so long as `\xJah` is defined to consume everything up to the token inserted by `\Jahr`.

Comment: David, I would suggest to edit this information into your answer (and then delete the comment, as will I do with mine).

Answer (score 6):

A different implementation with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\datetest}{ O{\Datum} m m m }
  {
   \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_datetest_date_seq { . } { #1 }
   \int_compare:nTF { \datetest_get:n { #2 } #3 #4 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \datetest_get:n #1
  {
   \prg_case_str:nnn { #1 }
     {
      { Jahr }  { \seq_item:Nn \l_datetest_date_seq { 2 } }
      { Monat } { \seq_item:Nn \l_datetest_date_seq { 1 } }
      { Tag }   { \seq_item:Nn \l_datetest_date_seq { 0 } }
     }
     { 0 }
  }
\seq_new:N \l_datetest_date_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\Datum}{04.8.2011}

\begin{document}

\datetest{Jahr}{=}{2011}{Jahr eq 2011}{Jahr neq 2011}

\datetest{Monat}{<=}{9}{$\le$}{$>$}

\newcommand{\mydate}{01.02.2003}

\datetest[\mydate]{Monat}{>}{3}{After March}{Before April}

\datetest[01.05.2010]{Monat}{>}{3}{After March}{Before April}
\end{document}
```

`\datetest` acts by default on `\Datum`, but a macro or an explicit date can be passed as optional argument. The item to test is the first argument, the type of test (`<`, `<=`, `=`, `>=`, or `>`) as second argument; then the number to test and what to do if the test is either true or false.

Note that the second argument is a string, not a command. One can extend the macros to define `\Jahr`, `\Monat` or `\Tag`, if so desired.

Comment: +1. Rather than `\tl_set:Nx` and `\tl_replace_all:Nnn`, I'd use `\seq_set_split:Nnx \l_foo_seq {.} {#1}`, then use `\seq_item:Nn` where you used `\clist_item:Nn`. It is cleaner because you are not converting a tl into a clist by hand. By the way, `\clist_set:Nn \l_foo_clist { a~, }` results in `\l_foo_clist` containing `a` only, so a clist is not simply a token list with some commas.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks, `\seq_set_split` is just what I was looking for.