# String test, with complicated arguments

Tags: fonts, conditionals, strings

I have a command `\mycom{}` which takes 1 argument. The command should perform a test on the argument and do something accordingly. For simple arguments, I can use `\ifthenelse`, but I need to consider more general arguments, e.g. containing commands or environments. 
The following MWE follows a solution for a more robust string test, which was given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42333/10157):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strtest}[2]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycom}[1]{%
\strtest{#1}{}%
{content :  empty}%
{content : #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\mycom{}

\mycom{coucou}
\end{document}
```

This works. But if i try to call `\mycom{\textbf{coucou}}`, then the compilation fails.

Comment: Ah, now I see! The quoted answer tells you that this test works only for simple strings, and suggests a way to cope with more complicated input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\pdfstrcmp` primitive fully expands its argument. Thus things go wrong with macros that cannot be expanded, which includes `\textbf`. You can prevent this using the `\unexpanded` primitive:

```
\newcommand{\strtest}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you want this to work cross-engine, you should load the `pdftexcmds` package and use `\pdf@strcmp`, which deals with the fact that XeTeX calls the primitive `\strcmp` and LuaTeX requires it is implemented in Lua.

Comment: Would you prefer `\unexpanded` or `\detokenize` in this case?

Comment: @egreg We've used `\unexpanded` in LaTeX3, as the idea is to prevent expansion rather than turn into a string _per se_ (which happens anyway). That I know of, there is no technical reason to prefer one approach over another.

Comment: So I guess this can be closed as a duplicate, as your answer is already included in mine.

Comment: thanks, it works. BY the way (i know it is another question...) i would like to follow the same logic, for a command with one argument, which would perform a test of the form `IF #1=a OR #1= b THEN`. I mean, with an `OR`. But i don't manage to do it.

Comment: @nicolasroy http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42791/4427 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41830/4427 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42713/4427

Comment: @egreg, Joseph, there is one technical reason to prefer `\unexpanded`: it is slightly more efficient since we move around less tokens: `\pdfstrcmp` converts the tl to a string internally, rather than having to first produce character tokens. For instance, `\edef\x{\exp_not:c{\prg_replicate:nn{100000}x}} \edef\x{\prg_replicate:nn{1000}\x} \str_if_eq:xxTF{\tl_to_str:N\x}{}{}{}` blows up when trying to build a string with 100002000 tokens, whereas using `\exp_not:o` works fine.

Comment: This solution works perfectly, when i use it in a command like \mycom. Now, i would like to use it with an environment defined with `\NewEnviron` instead of a command, and to refer to `\BODY` instead of `#1`. But this does not work... precisely because of `\BODY` is not expanded, because of the `\unexpanded`. HOw could i force the expansion of `\BODY` in the call of the command `\strtest` ?

Comment: You can get a single expansion using `\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}`.

Comment: Well, i don't get it. Do you mean : 

`\NewEnviron{monenv}{
\strtest{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}{}
{content : empty}
{content : \BODY}
}`
?

Comment: I think the correct solution, inside the `monenv` should rather be : `\expandafter\strtest\expandafter{\BODY}{}`. But i don't feel so sure with `expandafter`'s and all that stuff ... :(

Comment: @nicolasroy One for a separate question, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I want to show an alternative. Based on the LaTeX3 engine one approach is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3,}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \mycom } { m } {
 \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
   {content:~empty}
   {content:~#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mycom{}

\mycom{coucou}

\mycom{\textbf{coucou}}
\end{document}
```

Base on the comments question you can compare strings with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mystringcase}{  m }
  {
    \prg_case_str:nnn { #1 }
         {
          { a }  { Your~string~\textbf{a} }
          { b }  { Your~string~\textbf{b} }
          { c }  { Your~string~\textbf{c} }
         }       
         { Not~in~list }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mystringcase{a}

\mystringcase{b}

\mystringcase{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\tl_if_empty:nTF`?

Comment: @JosephWright: Because of the Argument `#1` I don't know the contents and I want to avoid unwanted expansion.

Comment: `\tl_fi_empty:nTF` does no expansion, and is therefore safe with any input.