# String test, with an OR connector

Tags: conditionals

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43601/10157), a solution is given to the problem of defining a command which tests equality of two strings, sufficiently robust (in comparison to `\ifthenelse`) to admit complicated arguments (e.g. containing commands or environments). 
But now, i would like to adapt it to perform a test on 1 argument in the form "IF arg= a OR arg=b THEN ... ELSE ...", where "a" and "b" or fixed. My attempt is :

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testOR}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{a}=\z@
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{b}=\z@
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
    \else%
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
    \fi%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\testIfNotTrivial{a}{true}{false} - 
\testIfNotTrivial{b}{true}{false} - 
\testIfNotTrivial{coucou}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

But it does not have the expected (from me) behaviour : `false - False - true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a MWE this is untested but in your second branch the`\expandafter` only gets rid of one `\fi` you still have the outer `\fi` left so looks like you would want

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{b}=\z@
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\fi
```

(no need for `%` after a command name)

Answer (score 6):

You *really* should give LaTeX3 a try, if you have many tests like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\testOR}{m}
  {
   \bool_if:nTF
     {
      \str_if_eq_p:nn { #1 } { a } || \str_if_eq_p:nn { #1 } { b }
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\testOR{a}{true}{false} --
\testOR{b}{true}{false} --
\testOR{coucou}{true}{false} --
\testOR{\textbf{coucou}}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

This gives

> true – true – false – false

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. I'm just afraid of learning new syntaxes...

Comment: Where could i find an introduction to these latex3 commands ?