# Check options in \newcommand or \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, xparse

I'm trying to implement a custom command that is called like this:

```
\mycommand[hello][world]{mandatory1}{mandatory2}
```

OR:

```
\mycommand[hello,world]{mandatory1}{mandatory2}
```

However, I can't figure out how one can check the value of the two options - I want to check if they are really "hello" and "world" and nothing else, not "x" and "y", etc.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
 \NewDocumentCommand{o o m m}{
    if(#1 == "hello"){...} else {...}
    if(#2 == "world"){...} else {...}
}
```

How can I do this? I already found `\IfValueTF{...}` in `xparse`, but I can't check the value of an option with that - only if it was given or not.

Comment: You want to do a string test: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/string-test-with-complicated-arguments or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43670/string-test-with-an-or-connector, or use a classical method `\def\@tempa{#1}\def\@tempb{2}\ifx\@tempa\@tempb...`.

Comment: You want the `[..][..]` to be mandatory or optional? I'm not sure I understand. What do you need the optional arguments to be by default? You can compare strings with `\str_if_eq:nnTF` from expl3.

Comment: Manuel: The square bracket options should be optional. There is no default value for them, they can either be given or not.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments to my original question I was able to figure out a solution to my problem. However, I'm not sure if it is really appropriate. It works, but maybe there is a better solution?

```
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{o o m m}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{hello}}
        {hello}
        {not hello}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{world}}
        {world}
        {not world}
}
```

Comment: Another option is with expl3 (which is loaded by `xparse`). Put `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` around that code and use `\str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { hello } { yes ~ hello } { not ~ hello }`.

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar command using `xparse` for setting languages:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\setlanguage}[1]{%
    \IfEq{#1}{da}{%
         \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indhold} % TOC Name
         }%
         {}% if not, then do this
}%
```

In the document, you would use:

```
\setlanguage{da} % or some other ISO 639-1 code
```

Also see

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33753/13552